# I can't use the apploading on my react native. It wont work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I keep getting this error: [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88KPa.png)

Here is the code that im using to import my custom google fonts:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Home from "./screens/home";
import { View } from "react-native";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";

const getFonts = () =>
  Font.loadAsync({
    "poppins-regular": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),
    "poppins-bold": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"),
  });

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return <Home />;
  } else {
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={getFonts} onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)} />
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my Json Package:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.8.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I can't seem to find the error or fix it. I did this with another project before and it worked. The getting the font info is exactly the same. The only thing i can think of is maybe my packages are outdated atm? but Im not sure which package to even update.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I can see from your package.json that you are at expo SDK 40 (latest release as of now)

**AppLoading has been extracted from the expo package in SDK 40**

If you want to use this component, you should run expo install expo-app-loading and import AppLoading from its own package: import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';. This is part of an ongoing effort to make the expo package as lightweight as possible.

Check the expo blog [here.](https://dev.to/expo/expo-sdk-40-is-now-available-1in0)

Steps:
**STEP 1:** `expo install expo-app-loading`

**STEP 2:**

replace `import { AppLoading } from "expo";`

by  `import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';`

**STEP 3:** Restart your expo dev server (expo start)

Comment: Thanks for this! it's no longer giving me the error. However, it's not loading anything on my phone when i run it on expo.

It's giving me this error in my terminal though:
AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading:
Error: AppLoading onError prop is required if startAsync is provided

Comment: By any chance would you know what i should be doing here? Is it my async syntax now since the new expo update?

Comment: Can you explain to me what is happening exactly? and some code would be nice :)

Comment: I figured it out! i had to use the syntax for the new apploading! i just needed to add onError={console.warn}. Thanks for your help! I appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that the first time reloading the app (with expo), the fonts were not loading.

After deleting, rewriting and saving the fontFamily inside of my **StyleSheet**, the text was being styled with the right font, as the app updates automatically every time you save a file.
I just couldn't make it work at the first load.

I solved the issue by putting a return in front of the **Font.loadAsync()** function:

```js
const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({               // <- add return here
    "open-sans": require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"),
    "open-sans-bold": require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf"),
  });
};
```

Now the AppLoading's **startAsync** gets the promise correctly and the fonts are loaded right after loading the app, without errors

```js
const [isDataLoaded, setIsDataLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (!isDataLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setIsDataLoaded(true)}
        onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
      />
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to add the **return** keyword infront of font.loadAsync

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up, as of today, using startAsync method is depracted in `expo-app-loading`, you can use `useEffect` instead and run your function as you would like and handle all the errors there,

```
  useEffect(() => {
      const getAsyncData = async () => {
           // Do my async request
           setIsReady(true); 
      }
      getAsyncData ();
   }, [])
```

Assuming you have something like `const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);` in your code

Answer (score 0):

for me the following steps result: 
STEP 1: stop device 
STEP 2: expo install expo-app-loading 
STEP 3: add the next line: import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'; 
STEP 4: 
if (!isDataLoaded) { 
return ( 
<AppLoading 
    startAsync={fetchFonts} 
    onFinish={() => setIsDataLoaded(true)} 
    onError={(err) => console.log(err)} 
    /> 
  ); 
}

Answer (score -1):

the same case as paulob, but my SDK is 50, and I did solved by change the

```js
import { Apploading } from 'expo'
```

to

```js
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen'
```

due to the depreciation of expo-app-loading from SDK 45 article. of course you need to install expo-splash-screen to use it by typing: npx expo install expo-splash-screen in terminal and hit Enter. After finish installation just replace by import SplashScreen then change the Apploading component to SplashScreen too
Good luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).