# How to solve project Error: Element type is invalid?

Tags: react-native, expo

**Hello, guys!**

I'm working with [this repository](https://github.com/Minte-grace/Dating_UI) and can't start an Expo project. Here is the full mistake:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

**package.json**:

```js
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/montserrat": "^0.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^5.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^9.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**App.js**:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import ChatStackNavigator from './src/navigations/Navigator';
import {
  useFonts,
  Montserrat_700Bold,
  Montserrat_600SemiBold,
  Montserrat_800ExtraBold
} from '@expo-google-fonts/montserrat';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo'


const App = () => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Montserrat_700Bold,
    Montserrat_600SemiBold,
    Montserrat_800ExtraBold
  });
  if(!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading/>
  }
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <ChatStackNavigator/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
export default App;
```

**UPDATE!**

I reinstalled `node_modules`:

1. Go to your project directory in `Node.js Command Prompt` using `cd`
2. Use `yarn` or `npm` (I use `npm`) to install `rimraf`

`npm install rimraf -g`

`rimraf node_modules`

3. Now install all your modules back using `npm install`
4. I have this **mistake in a browser**:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

and this **mistake in a console**:

C:/../DatingApp/App.js
Attempted import error: 'AppLoading' is not exported from 'expo'.

I go to `App.js` and see this code:

```
import { AppLoading } from 'expo'
```

...

```
if(!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading/>
  }
```

This is incorrect usage of `AppLoading`. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261890/i-cant-use-the-apploading-on-my-react-native-it-wont-work-properly).
So, what's I'm going to do:

1. Using console and `npm` I do: `npm install expo-app-loarding`
2. In my code I replace `import { AppLoading } from 'expo'` by `import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';`
3. I save my project and using console I do: `expo start --web`

I have another mistake in console and now I know how to solve it

**UPDATE 2**:

`npm install expo-app-loading` did not work.

[image]

I tried `expo install expo-app-loading` it also did not work.

[image]

I deleted these lines of code from `App.js`:

1.

```
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

2. 

```
if(!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading/>
  }
```

Now the app is working!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried deleting your node modules and reinstalling the project? Sometimes I get this error and that fixes it.

Comment: I edited my question with the answer. Thank you!